# How to set the 'price' to align centered in Woocommerce?

Tags: html, css, woocommerce, price

I am trying to center the price amount in my Woocommerce related products. I can center the product title, but not the price. How can I fix this?

I've tried different combinations of codes (separated by '//'), but none seem to work.

```
.woocommerce .products .product .price
{text-align:center}

//

.fusion-price-rating{
    justify-content: flex-end;
}

//

.price {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: right;
}
```

Comment: Hi, Can you please add the code snippet or a jsfiddle to understand your issue better

Comment: add your HTML Code Here

Comment: It's about this page: http://2019.vrelax.com/product/vrelax-licentie/. At the bottom, the related products' price is aligned to the left, instead of the center. I would like this to be centered as well. :-)

Comment: working fine what the problem?

Comment: what you want `left` or `center` or `right` ?

Answer (score 0):

Please add `text-align: center` as below

```css
.product .entry-summary .price {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 10px;
  text-align: center; // Added
}
```